# Basic for/while loop questions

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

Very new to python, trying to answer the following questions, but not sure how to approach it so that the loop is doing the work.

Use for loop or while loop to calculate 5!

Use for loop or while loop to calculate ∑ 
5
=1

Use for loop or while loop to calculate ∏ 
9
=3

Use for loop or while loop to calculate 3
8

This was my answer for the first one and similar answers for the rest.

```
for i in range (1,2):
  for_list = [3,4,5]
  sum_values = ((i+1)*i) * for_list[0] * for_list[1] * for_list[2]
  print (sum_values)
```

Comment: Edit your post so its easier to read, there is a `code` formatter

Comment: Sorry about that, didn't realize it came out like that, I edited it so it should be easier to read, thanks!

Comment: This isn't actually using a loop for anything, the "loop" here could just as easily be replaced with `i = 1` and dedenting the "loop" body, and it would still work. The first two problems here should simplify to `accumulator = *somebasevalue*`, `for i in range(1, 6):` `accumulator *someaccumulatingoperation* i`. Note of course, that for non-learning related purposes, you'd just use [`math.factorial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.factorial) for #1 and (if I'm reading right) [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) for #2.

Answer (score 1):

To calculate the factorial of any number, you coud defined a function that looks quite similar to this

```
def factorial(n):
  result = 1
  for i in range(2,n+1):
    result *= i
  return result
```

So, to use the above funcion to calulate the factorial of any number, just pass in that number as argument to the function e.g

```
print(factorial(5)) # 120
```

But, if you specifically want to calculate the factorial of 5, you could have a for loop that looks similar to this

```
result = 1
for i in range(2,6):
  result = result * i

print(result)
```